# How to use a line break in an alert/prompt dialog in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, line-breaks

I have been having trouble with formatting a dialog in `Google Apps Script`. I would like to have a dialog using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(prompt)` which has a line break so I can have a list. I tried using `\n`, `\\n`, and `<br />`, but nothing appears to work and I can't find anything anywhere on whether or not it is even possible. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want a dialog, then make a dialog with `HtmlService` and serve it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went through this same problem. This actually works:

```
\r\n
```

Comment: Interesting, it really does work with the .alert() function.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this type of messaging inside a Google doc using the following code:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('your long doc ID');
var body = doc.getBody();
body.appendParagraph("Line 1");
body.appendParagraph("Line 2");
```

or you could do it in a sheet using:

```
sheet.appendRow(['line1col1','col2']);
sheet.appendRow(['line2col1','col2']);
```